# Automatic code analysis on check-in in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, code-analysis

We are working on a legacy WinForms project which has neglected basic coding standards and now has a lot of classes with 20k+ lines of code.

The problem is that most developers on this project have only worked on legacy technologies and it's a bit hard to educate them on the importance of proper code form.

I was thinking of implementing a check in our TFS server that would prevent them from checking in the code if the size of one (or more) of the changed files is over 2000 lines and the new version is larger than the previous one.

This would prevent files from growing, they would just decrease in size.

Unfortunately, as far as I can see, the TFS code analysis rule sets only take into account the current state of the code that is checked in, and there's no way of making a comparison with the previous version (workspace version vs server version).

Would there be a way of implementing this at the TFS server level, so that people are prevented from adding lines to files, but they are not forced to refactor a 20k class just to commit their changes?

Comment: Look at SonarQube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no default way to achieve your requirement. You need to customize a check in policy to compare the local file to a server copy of the same file.

The first step you need is to get the latest version of the file from TFS. Then compare the local file with the downloaded file. Here is [a blog](https://paulselles.wordpress.com/2014/01/08/team-foundation-server-api-programmatically-downloading-files-from-source-control/) shares an example of how to retrieve the latest version for a given file:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string teamProjectCollectionUrl = "https://YourTfsUrl/tfs/YourTeamProjectCollection";
            string filePath = @"C:\project\myfile.cs";

            // Get the version control server
            TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(teamProjectCollectionUrl));
            VersionControlServer versionControlServer = teamProjectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

            // Get the latest Item for filePath
            Item item = versionControlServer.GetItem(filePath, VersionSpec.Latest);

            // Download and display content to console
            string fileString = string.Empty;

            using (Stream stream = item.DownloadFile())
            {
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);

                    // Use StreamReader to read MemoryStream created from byte array
                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray())))
                    {
                        fileString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(fileString);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```